# Two questions regarding cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that if $G$ is cyclic group of order $n$, then it is isomorphic to $Z_n$. I have two questions regarding this

1. Does every finite abelian group have to be isomorphic to $Z_n$ for some $n$?
2. If a group is abelian, must it be cyclic?

Comment: Hint: Consider abelian groups of order $4$.

Comment: I encourage you to explore for yourself first, but if you give up, look for the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Answer (score 4):

The answers to both questions are **no**. One counterexample for both questions is an abelian group with $4$ elements. Do you know which one?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the [Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification) All finitely generated *abelian* groups can be decomposed into the direct sum of infinite cyclic groups and cyclic groups of finite order.

Also, a group $$\mathbb Z_{mn} \cong \mathbb Z_m \oplus \mathbb Z_n  \iff \gcd(m, n) = 1$$

So in any case where we have $G = \mathbb Z_m \oplus \mathbb Z_n$ with $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, $G\cong \mathbb Z_{mn}$ and is hence cyclic.

So, for example, we have two *abelian* groups, up to isomorphism, of order $4$:

$$\mathbb Z_4\\ \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2 \not\cong \mathbb Z_4$$

Note that we have, first, a cyclic abelian group of order $4$, and second, since $\gcd(2, 2) = 2\neq 1$, we have an abelian, but *not* cyclic, group.